# Python: Writing a Dict to CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am attempting to run regression against a really large csv file. However, many of the columns were constructed to represent binary situations, and only the 1 values got logged in the csv. The values that should be 0 are listed as '' (empty)

Is there a way that I can parse through all the values in a CSV file so that '' values get logged as 0 instead?

Ex: I would like to convert this:

```
One,Two,Three,Four
1,,,1
,,1,        
1,,1,
,,,1
```

Into something like this:

```
One,Two,Three,Four
1,0,0,1
0,0,1,0     
1,0,1,0
0,0,0,1
```

This is the code I have so far. I used `DictReader` in order to fix the values I needed to update. However, **I'm completely stuck on how to get the updated `dict` back into the 'fixed' csv file**. Everything I've tried so far has broken.

```
import csv
import pandas

with open('TestCSV.csv','r') as infile,open('Fixed.csv','w') as outfile:
 r = csv.DictReader(infile)
 w = csv.DictWriter(outfile)
 for row in r:
   for val in row:
      if len(row[val])<1:
         row[val]='0'
   #w.write_row(row) # Produces TypeError
```

Comment: Are you actually wanting to create a dataframe in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace values:

```
df = pd.read_csv('.../temp.csv')

# Replace quotes
[df.replace(x, 0, inplace=True) for x in ['""', "''"]]

# Replace NAs
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# Save to csv
df.to_csv('.../Fixed.csv')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for row in r:
   for val in row:
      if len(row[val])<1:
         row[val]='0'
   w.write_row(row)
```

you have to actually tell it to write the row

Comment: I had tried that. I keep getting an error saying.TypeErrror:__init__() takes at least 3 arguments(2 given)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the csv module there are multiple errors in your code you need to fix, you need to pass the `fieldnames` to `csv.DictWriter` then write them and the length of the empty string will be `1` so `csv.DictWriter` will never be True so nothing will be changed:

```
with open('in.csv', 'r') as infile, open('Fixed.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=r.fieldnames)
    w.writeheader()
    for row in r:
        for k, v in row.items():
            if v == "''":
                row[k] = "0"
        w.writerow(row)
```

To change the original file it would actually be easier just use `str.replace` and open the file without the csv module, to change the original file you can use [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) with `inplace=True`:

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input("in.csv",inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write(line.replace("''","0"))
```

Output:

```
One,Two,Three,Four
1,0,0,1
0,0,1,0
1,0,1,0
0,0,0,1
```

Or using a [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) with [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move), writing to the tempfile the replacing the original file with the updated file using move:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
```

from shutil import move

```
with open('TestCSV.csv', 'r') as infile, NamedTemporaryFile(dir=".", delete=False) as  outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.replace("''", "0"))

move(outfile.name,'TestCSV.csv')
```

Or if you want a new file just do the same using `file.write`:

```
with open('TestCSV.csv','r') as infile,open('Fixed.csv','w') as outfile:
     for line in infile:
         outfile.write(line.replace("''","0"))
```

You only have either an empty string or a "1" in each line so it is simpler just to replace the empty strings.

You could also do it quite easily with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) using a Dataframe and [df.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)  if you intend to actually create a df with your data:

```
df = pd.read_csv("in.csv")
df.replace("''","0",inplace=True)
print(df)

  One Two Three Four
0   1   0     0    1
1   0   0     1    0
2   1   0     1    0
3   0   0     0    1
# work on df
.......
# save results to csv
df.to_csv("fixed.csv",index=False)
```

Output:

```
One,Two,Three,Four
1,0,0,1
0,0,1,0
1,0,1,0
0,0,0,1
```

Comment: i tried the pandas version of your solution and got a syntax error at df.replace("''",'0',inplace=True).

Comment: Then you must have a typo.

Comment: I've been working off of two computers. My mac for stack overflow, and an ASUS for my work stuff. I'm not allowed to transfer customer information over email so I've been hand typing everything. I transferred 100% over to my PC as of this comment.

Comment: The   `.......`  just means whatever work you have to do, it is not actually code